# Why is a filter available in another angular module

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular application and a few modules. The modules are organized as follows:

I have two modules: helpers and maps. In the helpers module I've defined an angular filter helpers.filter(...)

The helpers module is defined as follows: `var helpers = new angular.module('helpers', ['ngResource', 'ui.router']);`

The other module, maps is defined as follows: `var maps = new angular.module('maps', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitze']`

And then there is the app module, defined like: `var app = new angular.module('app', ['helpers','maps'])`

How come that the filter I defined on the *helpers* module is available in the *maps*?

I assume it is because **app** is like a parent and the children inherit everything that is available on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482799/angularjs-how-to-correct-inject-service-from-another-module-that-is-not-depend/24483476#answer-24483476)**.

It's not just filters, but services, controllers, directives etc.
This is because there is (normally) one `$injector` per app, so all modules and submodules in the app have access to the same "injectables".